# Volume Control Notification Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyqt, libnotify

I am using PyQT for making Gui , in which i am controlling volume through button i am using amixer command line tool to increase and decrease the volume ,Can i also show the default notification come when user increase or decrease volume ?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
            volume = 60
            cmd ="notify-send \" \" -i notification-audio-volume-high -h int:value:"+str(volume)+" -h string:synchronous:volume"
            #print cmd
            os.system(cmd)
```